# Correct way for sign up with Twitter Using Devise and Omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, devise, omniauth

I am creating a rails app that requires sign up with twitter feature.And my application is based on email marketing service.Various types of email we will send user for the updates.

My concern here is that,twitter does not provide the email ID in response while authenticating a user via twitter API.

And now if I am creating that user in my database and allowing him to sign up by skipping some validation (Like email field is required). Then what should happen in the situation when my application will try to send the email to users.And this twitter user is not having email ID.
It will just skipped.

Is there any proper flow that I can use,so my app will work in correct flow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter doesn´t give you the email via API.

This works if you are using omniauth-facebook gem for example, but twitter doesn´t offer you the email - you have to create a workaround.

For example ask the user in a second step to fill in his/her email adress.